# ttyACM0 does not exist in jetson racecar TX2

Tags: linux, nvidia, tty, nvidia-jetson

I have a jetson racecar tx2 and this is its details:
NVIDIA Jetson TX2
L4T 32.2.1 [ JetPack 4.2.2 ]
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Kernel Version: 4.9.140-tegra
CUDA 10.0.326
CUDA Architecture: 6.2
OpenCV version: 3.4.0
OpenCV Cuda: YES
CUDNN: 7.5.0.56
TensorRT: 5.1.6.1
Vision Works: 1.6.0.500n
VPI: NOT_INSTALLED
Vulcan: 1.1.70

When is try to start teleport it gives me this error message:

```
Device not found: IMU or VESC not found -> /dev/ttyACM1 /dev/ttyACM0
```

I checked out ttyACM0 it doesnot exists I tried to installed ttyACM modules but it gives that module  and kernel versions are different.

the usb list as shown in figure:[USB List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zlwI.jpg)

anyone can help me please?